# "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" when returning JSON to client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, dangerous-request

I have an app that allows a user to edit email templates. The email templates employ HTML so the client sends HTML to the controller. I am using the Jodit HTML editor (https://xdsoft.net/jodit/) for the message body so users don't have to know HTML themselves. I can post the form and the controller accepts the request as the view model is decorated with the appropriate [AllowHtml] attribute; indeed, `ModelState.IsValid` is true. The error occurs when the data is returned to the client; the controller does not return the json object but instead returns an error.

The question is, how do I prevent asp.net from marking this as dangerous on return?

Note, this app deals with PII so not validating requests is not an option.

Here is the error (Adding the complete error in case someone finds that helpful):

> Server Error in '/ReallyAwesomeApp' Application.
>
> *A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (messagetext="<font color="#000000...").*
>
> **Description:** ASP.NET has
> detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it
> might include HTML markup or script. The data might represent an
> attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a
> cross-site scripting attack. If this type of input is appropriate in
> your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly
> allow it. For more information, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A
> potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
> (messagetext="<font color="#000000...").
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous
> Request.Form value was detected from the client (messagetext="<font
> color="#000000...").]    System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String
> value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource
> requestCollection) +322
> System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass280_0.b__0(String
> key, String value) +18
> System.Web.HttpValueCollection.EnsureKeyValidated(String key) +86
> System.Web.HttpValueCollection.Get(String name) +17
> System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.CreateOutputCachedItemKey(String
> path, HttpVerb verb, HttpContext context, CachedVary cachedVary) +694
> System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.CreateOutputCachedItemKey(HttpContext
> context, CachedVary cachedVary) +56
> System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs
> eventArgs) +1226
> System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +200    System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.b__0() +24    System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +100
> System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0() +17
> Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase
> context, Action step) +64
> System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.b__0(Action
> nextStepAction) +54    System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action
> executionStep) +84    System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0()
> +17    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase
> context, Action step) in
> E:\A_work\21\s\WEB\Src\Web\Web.Shared.Net\ApplicationInsightsHttpModule.cs:164
> System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.b__0(Action
> nextStepAction) +54    System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action
> executionStep) +84
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +100
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
> completedSynchronously) +73
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
> ASP.NET Version:4.8.4075.0

Here is my view model:

```
public class EmailTemplateViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmailTemplates { get; set; }

    public List<EmailAttachmentViewModel> EmailAttachments { get; set; } = new List<EmailAttachmentViewModel>();

    public string CreateUserIdentifier { get; set; }

    public int TemplateID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Template Name")]
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Subject")]
    public string EmailSubject { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Message Text")]
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my return model (Found this little gem here on SO):

```
public class JsonReturnModel<T>
{
    public List<ClientError> ClientErrors { get; internal set; } = new List<ClientError>();

    public T Data { get; internal set; }

    public bool LoggedIn { get; internal set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public List<ServerError> ServerErrors { get; internal set; } = new List<ServerError>();

    public bool Success { get; internal set; }
}
```

Here's my Controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult EditEmailTemplate(EmailTemplateViewModel model)
    {
        RepositoryResult result = new RepositoryResult();
        JsonReturnModel<EmailTemplateViewModel> returnModel = new JsonReturnModel<EmailTemplateViewModel>();

        if (model == null)
        {
            returnModel.Success = false;
            returnModel.Message = "No data sent to server.";

            return Json(returnModel);
        }
        
        EmailTemplateModel newModel = null;
        result = DataManager.UpdateEmailTemplate(model.ToEmailTemplateModel());

        if (result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            newModel = (EmailTemplateModel)result.ResultingObject;
            returnModel.Data = newModel.ToEmailTemplateViewModel();
        }
        
        returnModel.Success = result.IsSuccessful;
        returnModel.Message = result.Message;
        
        return Json(returnModel);
    }
```

And finally the Ajax that gets called via JQuery:

```
$('#save-btn').on('click', function (event) {
    var rawHtml = $('#message-editor').html();
    $('#MessageText').val(ESCM.joditEditor.value);

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: ESCM.EmailPostUrl,
        data: $("form").serialize(), 
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.IsSuccessful || data.Success) {
                $('#email-template-editor').click();
                $('#TemplateID').val(data.Data.TemplateID);
                $('#TemplateID').change();
            }
            DisplayMessage(data);
        },
        error: function (errorData) {
            console.debug(errorData);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You mean controller action is returning from `return Json(returnModel);` and after that you are seeing error? Is there any other web request happening after response is returned on client code in `success: function (data) {`. What if you comment the code in `success: function (data) {` block?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, That is exactly what I mean; the the action method's code runs all the way to the return statement, . Not sure what you mean by comment the success code. I did set a break point on the if statement but it was never hit.

Comment: Seems like you have to disable request validation for this specific request, as described by the link error message asks you to visit.

Comment: *If this type of input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow it*. Does this link help at all: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874 ?